# Use TSP source in DSS demo WebApp with authentication certificate

Tags: xml, digital-signature, signature, p12, timestamping

I try to change mock timestamp service in `DSS Demo Webapp`. The demonstration uses a dummy timestamp source by default. I found it is defined in dss.properties file.

```
# TSA
tsp-source = classpath:config/tsp-config.xml
```

I checked [tsp-config.xml](https://github.com/esig/dss-demonstrations/blob/master/dss-demo-webapp/src/main/resources/config/tsp-config.xml), but it contains just authentication certificate details, not the URL of service, which should be replaced.
I modified xml file as follows:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

    <bean id="passwordProtection" class="java.security.KeyStore.PasswordProtection">
        <constructor-arg name="password" value="ks-password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tsa-token" class="eu.europa.esig.dss.token.KeyStoreSignatureTokenConnection">
        <constructor-arg name="ksFile" type="java.io.File" value="classpath:myAuthCert.p12" />
        <constructor-arg name="ksType" value="PKCS12" />
        <constructor-arg name="ksPassword" ref="myAuthCertPass" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="tspSource" class="eu.europa.esig.dss.x509.tsp.MockTSPSource">
        <property name="dataLoader" ref="timestampDataLoader" />
        <property name="tspServer" value="myTSPSourceURL" />
        <property name="token" ref="tsa-token" />
        <property name="alias" value="self-signed-tsa" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="timestampDataLoader" class="eu.europa.esig.dss.client.http.commons.TimestampDataLoader">
        <property name="proxyConfig" ref="proxyConfig" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I found some info about `OnlineTSPSource` class too, but cannot find it in source and not sure, how does authentication happen with this.

Comment: OnlineTSPSource is here: https://github.com/esig/dss/blob/627a299f3f4240e69468e3ebeb4af5cf354f2331/dss-service/src/main/java/eu/europa/esig/dss/service/tsp/OnlineTSPSource.java

Comment: @Egl : It was submitted as a feature request, it isn't yet developed: https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/tracker/browse/DSS-1727